# Create a spatial polygons data frame that preserves overlapping features with another spatial polygons data frame but does not clip polygon extent

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial, r-raster

I have been using the `intersect()` function from the raster package in R to clip a spatial polygons data frame (HUC-4 watersheds) to the extent of another spatial polygons data frame (a region consisting of Colorado, Idaho, Montana, Utah, and Wyoming).

I want to preserve the entire extent of the spatial polygons that overlap with the spatial data frame I am clipping to. Using `intersect()` clips the HUC-4 watersheds so that they do not extend past the extent of the states being clipped to.

The watershed data that I am using can be downloaded from: ftp://rockyftp.cr.usgs.gov/vdelivery/Datasets/Staged/Hydrography/WBD/National/GDB/ (WBD_National_GDB.zip).

The data for the region encompassing Colorado, Utah, Idaho, Wyoming, and Montana was extracted from county data available here: https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/tiger-line-shapefile-2017-nation-u-s-current-county-and-equivalent-national-shapefile.

The code I am using to do the clip with the `intersect()` function is as follows:

```
library(raster)
library(dplyr)
library(spdplyr)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)

# albers equal area projection
proj <- CRS("+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=37.5 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs ")

counties <- readOGR(dsn = "./data/tl_2017_us_county/tl_2017_us_county.shp")

# filtering out only counties in our 5 states of interest
counties <- counties %>%
  filter(STATEFP %in% c("08", "16", "30", "49", "56"))

# transforming to albers projection
counties <- spTransform(counties, proj)

# create a region shapefile (to clip watersheds with)
region <- gUnaryUnion(counties)

# Make Region into a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
row.names(region) <- as.character(1:length(region))
region_data <- c("West")
region_data <- as.data.frame(region_data)
colnames(region_data) <- "Region"

region <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(region, region_data)

file <- "./data/WBD_National_GDB/WBD_National_GDB.gdb"

# huc4 watersheds
huc4 <- readOGR(dsn = file, layer = "WBDHU4")

# transforming to albers projection
huc4 <- spTransform(huc4, proj)

# selecting only huc4 watersheds that intersect with our states of interest
huc4_clip <- raster::intersect(huc4, region)

# plot the result
plot(huc4_clip)
```

I want an output file that does not clip the extent of the spatial polygons that are on the edge of the region of interest, but does not include any spatial polygons that do not directly overlap with the region of interest. Are there any other functions I can use that are similar to `intersect()` but that do not clip the extent of the spatial polygons on the region border?

Comment: The answer is yes, but we cannot help you unless you provide a minimal (as simple as possible) reproducible example. Perhaps see `?raster::intersect` for inspiration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question properly, you could use function `gIntersects` to find out which watersheds intersect your region, and then extract only those from the huc4 dataset. In practice, something like this could work:

```r
intersects <- which(gIntersects(huc4, region, byid = TRUE))
huc4_clip  <- huc4[intersects, ]
```

Comment: This works great, thank you! As a note, I found that using this method only works when spgeom2 in `gIntersects` (in this case that is region) is only one large polygon. I tried doing this with the spgeom2 as a states polygon, with multiple polygons for different states, and it gave me an error and did not work when I tried to extract the clip.

Comment: That's probably because if spgeom2 contains multiple features, then `gIntersects` returns a matrix telling which element of spgeom2 intersects each element of spgeom. A simple solution for this case could be to use something like `intersects <- which(colSums(gIntersects(polys_sp, filt_bbox, byid = TRUE)) > 0)`

Comment: Thanks again for your solutions @Ibusett. I've been dabbling in the `sf` package recently, and have found that using `st_intersects` is another excellent option here. For example, `huc4_clip <- huc4 %>% filter(st_intersects(region, huc4, sparse = FALSE))`. The `sparse=FALSE` preserves the data frame element of the sf object.